# Accordion from WP Plugin Advanced Gutenberg - Prevent to open first Accordion

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I´m using the accordion from plugin "Advanced Gutenberg" for Wordpress. The plugin by default opens the first tab. But I want to show all tabs closed. So I wrote a little script that close the first accordion on document ready:

```
$('.ui-accordion-content').css({
    'display' : 'none',
});
```

That worked. So all accordions have `display: none` by default. But if I click to open the first accordion now, it opens only after the second click. All other accordions opens after the first click.

Do you have an idea what´s the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following jQuery to get this done:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').first().click();
```

Hope this helps!